# How to load retrained_graph.pb and retrained_label.txt using pycharm editor

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, image-recognition

Using [pete warden](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) tutorials i had trained the inception network and training of which i am getting two files 
1.retrained_graph.pb 
2.retrained_label.txt

Using this i wanted to classify the flower image.
I had install pycharm and linked all the tensorflow library , i had also test the sample tensorflow code it is working fine.

Now when i run the label_image.py program which is

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys

image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

i am getting this error message

```
/home/chandan/Tensorflow/bin/python /home/chandan/PycharmProjects/tf/tf_folder/tf_files/label_image.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/chandan/PycharmProjects/tf/tf_folder/tf_files/label_image.py", line 7, in <module>
        image_path = sys.argv[1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could any one please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because it is expecting image name (with path) as an argument.

In pycharm go to View->Tool windows->Terminal.

It is same as opening separate terminal. And run

```
python label_image.py /image_path/image_name.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the command line argument by calling `sys.argv[1]`. So you need to give command line arguments to satisfy it. Looks like the argument required is a test image, you should pass its location as a parameter.

Pycharm should have a script parameters and interpreter options dialog which you can use to enter the required parameters.

Or you can call the script from a command line and enter the parameter via;

```
>python my_python_script.py my_python_parameter.jpg
```

---

**EDIT:**

According to the [documents](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-python.html) (I don't have pycharm installed on this computer), you should go to **Run/Debug configuration** menu and edit the configurations for your script. Add the absolute path of your file into **Script Parameters** box in quotes.

Or alternatively if you just want to skip the parameter thing completely, just get the path as `raw_input` (`input` in python3) or just simply give it to `image_path = r"absolute_image_path.jpg"`

Comment: could you please help me to pass command which is "python /tf_files/label_image.py /tf_files/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg" through pycharm

Comment: @Chandan I don't have pycharm installed, but editted the answer from what I can see on the web. Check it please.